# YouTube API v3 - Playlist: Get "lastPageToken"

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Im trying to retrieve the oldest video of a playlist using the youtube v3 API. Based on the fact that there's no YT-API-Param to sort the playlist result and the max-value of the max-results param is 50, i'm searching for other solutions.
Since the YouTube Data API v3 results are paginated (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list), i'm looking for a way to a get a "lastPageToken" or some such. 
Any ideas? Many thanks!